# IIS single sign on using Kerberos tickets

Tags: windows, iis, kerberos

Assuming there is an IIS server configured for single sign on and on top of it a few web applications - is it possible to track which application was accessed or for which web application the kerberos ticket was requested?

Meaning - is this info going to be present on AD logs or local windows logs?

And if the answer is yes, in which windows event will can the info be found?
Will it be in event 4678? None of the [documentation](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4768) I found specifies this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs should be found on IIS logs.

See this link [authentification loogging](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969060)